# Convergence speed of perceptron algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, perceptron, mathematics

I was reading the [convergence proof for the perceptron algorithm](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/courses/6998-2012/notes/perc.converge.pdf). It says under the assumption that there are some $R$, $\theta^*$ with $|\theta^*| = 1$ and $\gamma > 0$, such that $y_t(x_t\cdot \theta^*) \geq \gamma$ and $|x_t|\leq R$ for $t = 1, 2, \dots n$, the perceptron algorithm makes at most $\frac{R^2}{\gamma^2}$ errors.

What I didn't fully understand how $\theta^*$ was related to $x_t$ and how it affected the convergence of PLA. If I scale down all $x_t$ by a factor $k$, then I have $|x_t| \leq \frac{1}{k}R$, but what happens to $\theta^*$ and $\gamma$? Does scaling down $x_t$ gives a smaller upper bound and thus PLA converges faster? I personally believe how fast PLA converges is decided by how data is distributed rather than $|x_i|$, is it correct? Any hint or answer is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds more like a theoretical question, hence better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).